# How I can delete a line item that contain first and last name in a file several time on different line item?

Tags: notepad++

62705300019623531            0000009200AR000000027283 HILL , CLAY
62705300019623531            0000009200AR000000046485 HILL , CLAY
62705300019623531            0000009200AR000000027787 HILL, DORIS M

like on the file i post i have a huge file with different duplicate names, for example i want to delete the second line item for Hill Clay even the other numbers are not duplicate , i need only the first record (line Item) and remove the are lines that contain the same first and last name.
In Excel i can highlights the column and remove duplicate,it is not working for me, even when I use mark all or RegRex place? maybe I am using wrong path or formula ? please advise!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a task for an editor, although it could be done via (python) scripting of np++.

I would rather suggest using the awk interpreter (you can download native windows executable):

Create script.awk with content:

```
{ name=gensub(/^[0-9A-Z]+ [0-9A-Z]+ /, "", 1) }

$1 == oldnum && name==oldname {next}

{ print $0, oldnum=$1; oldname=name}
```

Then run

```
awk -f script.awk yourfile.txt > output.txt
```

And let's see how it's possible within np++ using the python scripting.
Assuming that the Python Script plugin and the python interpreter is installed, you can write this code selecting Plugins->Python Script->New Script (the identation levels must be kept):

```
from Npp import *

content = editor.getText()
newcontent = ""

oldnum=""
oldname=""
for line in content.splitlines():
    fields = line.split( None, 2)
    if fields[0] != oldnum or fields[2] != oldname:
        newcontent += line + "\n"
        oldnum = fields[0]
        oldname = fields[2]

editor.clearAll()       
editor.appendText( newcontent)
```

Just name it something like **dedup**.

Load your data file into a tab and within that tab, select Plugins->Python Scripts->Scripts->dedup
... and it should be ok now.

Comment: I just add Python,  What is the formula that i would use for Notepad ++ under Python?  not sure about Awk

Comment: Please , i do not want to install other software , what is the formula under Notepad++ ? thank you!  the file is a TXT file.

Comment: Just hold the line. I do know about the python plugin for np++ but have never used it so takes some time to get acquainted.

Comment: I learnt some tiny piece of the plugin. You can find the result at the end of the original answer.

Comment: Nothing happened can you tell me step by step how to do it

Comment: Are you sure you installed the python interpreter from here https://www.python.org/downloads/ (I used the v2.7.11 one) and you let the installer add the directory of python.exe to the PATH variable when it asked about it?

Comment: I thought i am using notepad ++ i wasn't sure that i need to install another software to do so, the Paython are already under plugins and not need to re-install ?

Comment: Python is a programming language that np++ uses to allow scripting. It uses a plugin called Python Script to be able to use the interpreter of the language itself. That interpreter is called python.exe in windows. So you need two things: the python plugin and the python interpreter that needs to be dowloaded and installed separately. Without either of them, scripting won't work.

Comment: I install it already, can you explain set by step how to do it please